# css for adding background color to div tag

Tags: html, css

I want to add background color to div tag.Now background color appears only in the center  of the div.I want to display it for whole div tag
I have one outer div box and marked it as 'b'.With in box div tag I have emp div.within emp div I created emp1 div which i want to display background color.
My problem is I want background color like which i marked in green but now It displayed in center how I drawn in red.
[image]

```css
.box{
  height: 400px;
 margin-top:40px;
  text-align: center;
}  
.emp,.cli,.doc{
  position:relative;
   
  height:175px;

  width: 200px;
 
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.emp1,.cli1,.doc1{
 position:relative;
  
 height:20px;
  background: #1e5799;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:13px;
 color:#fff;
}
```

```html
    <div class="box">
         <div class="emp">
            <div class="emp1">
                Employees
            </div>  <!--end of emp1 div -->
         </div>  <!--end of emp div --> 
         <div class="cli">
             <div class="cli1">
                Clients
            </div>  <!--end of cli1 div -->
         </div>  <!--end of cli div --> 
         <div class="doc">
             <div class="doc1">
                Documents
            </div>  <!--end of doc1 div -->
         </div>  <!--end of doc div -->  
     </div> <!--end of box div -->
```

Please run it in full screen.

Comment: You want the blue to be full width ? (It's more elegant as it is now, BTW
)

Comment: no green that is emp1 div

Comment: Dude, emp1 div is blue (#1e5799), do you want emp1 to be full width ?

Comment: ya I want to to full width

Comment: Remove the padding from `.emp` then ?

Comment: It's working nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove your padding of *.emp,.cli,.doc*
If you want spacing, put on your title:

```css
.box{
  height: 400px;
   margin-top:40px;
  text-align: center;
}  
.emp,.cli,.doc{
  position:relative;
  height:175px;
  width: 200px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.emp1,.cli1,.doc1{
   position:relative;
   height:20px;
    background: #1e5799;
   text-align:center;
   font-size:13px;
   color:#fff;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="box">
         <div class="emp">
            <div class="emp1">
                Employees
            </div>  <!--end of emp1 div -->
         </div>  <!--end of emp div --> 
         <div class="cli">
             <div class="cli1">
                Clients
            </div>  <!--end of cli1 div -->
         </div>  <!--end of cli div --> 
         <div class="doc">
             <div class="doc1">
                Documents
            </div>  <!--end of doc1 div -->
         </div>  <!--end of doc div -->  
     </div> <!--end of box div -->
```